# Changing task properties on task execution

Tags: gradle

I have a situation where I need to add some jar files to compileJava's classpath, but those files aren't available when the task is initially loaded in gradle. So, if I do something like this:

```
compileJava.classpath += files('path/to/file.jar')
```

... it won't work, because when compileJava is loaded upon start-up of gradle, `path/to/file.jar` doesn't exist. In a step prior to compileJava, I'm copying that jar file into the right place, so when compileJava runs, the file will be available... but because gradle didn't find it when loading the compileJava task, it won't be in the classpath. Is there a way to set the task's classpath a bit more dynamically? I've tried this:

```
compileJava {
    doFirst {
        classpath += files('path/to/file.jar')
    }
}
```

... but that didn't work. Apparently the modification to the task property didn't take effect. Is it possible to access the property during the task's run time? Is there an entirely better way of doing this? Perhaps using `dependencies`?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring `compileJava.classpath` with a file path that doesn't exist yet is not a problem at all, and there is no need to defer it. There must be some other problem with your build script.